# How do I enable self-serve raw data pulls in Microsoft BI stack?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a way to let the business users pull subsets of our customer data (custom list of columns, and custom filters on these columns) - e.g. for running marketing campaigns. We can create a flat, completely de-normalized customer table in DW that would have the superset of all the attributes the users could potentially need, and keep it updated by running daily ETL.

The issue is finding a simple information delivery mechanism within Microsoft Stack that would let non-technical users select a few columns they need (out of 100+ columns, perhaps grouped in categories for convenience), and apply filters.

I was thinking of Excel connected to SSAS tabular model, but then the users would have to use Excel pivot table, which is intended for analytical calculations, not pulling large lists of raw data. Power BI also does not seem right for this purpose.

I remember seeing the functionality I was looking for in Cognos Impromptu back in 2000, so I was hoping that it would be available in Microsoft Stack in 2018, but so far I have not found anything. Hopefully there is a simple solution, and I am just not looking in the right direction... Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Excel queries to your database should do it.  You don't need SSAS for this.  Use Excel as your front end (the V and C in MVC and SQL as the M).  Get users' parameters, build the query, get results from the db and display them in a worksheet.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for something that would be a little more user-friendly. If I understood you correctly, with Excel queries the users will have to enter server/db name, then find the table, then go through the query editor (Power Query) interface to get what they need - I am afraid this could be overwhelming for non-technical users.